# Is there any API, tool, websites that i can find how many German people moved to United States in recent 10 years?

Tags: data-request, usa, uses-of-open-data, python, germany

I need to do geographical population analysis on how many German people recently moved to US and started to living there, especially to the California. I know US government has open data policy but so far could not find any relevant api, tool, websites related with my problem.

I already checked this website https://www.census.gov/topics/population.html, and this page https://www.dhs.gov/immigration-statistics/nonimmigrant

Comment: The next US census will happen in 2020, so if you can wait that long there will be fresh data available in a year or so.

Comment: You could write them and ask, but it may be the kind of special request that requires human or government employee intervention, so there may not be an API.